# Make PushNotifications sent from own server visible in background on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, capacitor

In my Ionic App I'm receiving push notifications from my own server, through Firebase Cloud Messaging. I;m sending the notifications with a post request to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`. They have the `data` key set, with a `title`, a `body`, and `content-available` sent to 1.

In my app, I use Capacitor's Push Notifications plugin to receive the notifications, like this:

```
 PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', (notification: PushNotification) => {
   alert('Push received ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
 });
```

It's working as intended when the app is opened and visible, but when it's in the background, nothing happens until I open it again. Is there any way I can receive this messages while the app is in background?

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the steps here in the [firebase with Android app](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase/#integrating-firebase-with-the-android-app) guide.

1. Reinstall (must uninstall first) the app again in your device.
2. Insert your Device token here as in the screenshot below

[image: insert FCM token here]